# Where should a ViewModel sit in the directory structure of an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am about to create a ViewModel to pass some data to a View. So if the application structure is convention based. Where are the ViewModel definitions to be kept. 
I could create a new directory called ViewModels, but what is the RIGHT way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a widely accepted convention for this.

I have 'ViewModels' folder too.

Comment: Yup, there's no overwhelming convention. I suspect most people have a "ViewModels" folder, or plonk their view models in the generated "Models" folder (especially if their actual model is coming from another assembly).

Comment: Odd, I don't even put my ViewModels in a ViewModel folder in my MVC apps... I call them Controllers, usually.

Answer (score 3):

I keep my view models in the Models folder because my data models reside in a separate assembly.

Comment: Even better. I dislike this style of naming too (i.e. adding Service postfix to service class name if it's in .Services namespace already).

Comment: Ok... services seems to be a bad example because services are usually named with verb. But the idea remains.

Answer (score 1):

We've reluctantly settled on a models folder as well even though our views and controllers are in separate assemblies.  We painted ourselves into the corner since we also use some of our WCF client-side DTOs directly in the view but those WCF client-side DTOs are generated in our controllers assembly.  I [blogged about our dilemma](http://blog.trinition.org/2009/08/separating-mvc-projects-in-wcf-world.html) in some greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

I keep all VM in a separate assembly (dll), so you can run tests easily against them - even outside ASP.NET scope...

Comment: There can't be that much to test with view models?